# pixelLabelDatastore from loaded image in workspace

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

I have multiple small *.mat files, each containing 4 input images (`template{1:4}` and a second channel `template2{1:4}`) and 4 output images (`region_of_interests{1:4}`), a binarized ('mask') image to train a deep neural network.

I basically followed an example on Mathworks and [it suggests to use a function](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/images/multispectral-semantic-segmentation-using-deep-learning.html) (in this example `@matreader`) to read in custom file formats.

However ...

1. It seems impossible to load multiple images from one *.mat file using any load function as it only allows one output, and imageDatastore doen't seem to allow loading data from workspace. How could this be achieved?
2. Similarly, it seems impossible to load a `pixelLabelDatastore` from a workspace variable. As a workaround I ended up saving the contents of my *.mat file to an image (using `imwrite`, saving to `save_dir`), and re-loading it from there (in this case, the function doesn't even allow to load *.mat files.). (How) can this be achieved without re-saving the file as image?

Here my failed attempt to do so:

---

```
%main script
image_dir = pwd; %location of *.mat files
save_dir  = [pwd '/a/']; %location of saved output masks
imds = imageDatastore(image_dir,'FileExtensions','.mat','ReadFcn',@matreader); %load template (input) images
pxds = pixelLabelDatastore(save_dir,{'nothing','something'},[0 255]);%load region_of_interests (output) image

%etc, etc, go on to train network

%matreader function, save as separate file
function data=matreader(filename)
  in=1; %give up the 3 other images stored in template{1:4}
  load(filename); %loads template and template2, containing 4x input images each
  data=cat(3,template{in},template2{in}); %concatinate 2 template input images in 3rd dimension
end

%generate example data for this question, will save into a file 'example.mat' in workspace
for ind=1:4
  template{ind}=rand([200,400]);
  template2{ind}=rand([200,400]);
  region_of_interests{ind}=rand([200,400])>.5;
end
save('example','template','template2','output')
```

Comment: please at least comment downvotes, so authors can improve the question...

Comment: As for question 1. The syntax is `data=load(file.mat)` where `data` then will be a struct with fields refering to all variables in the file `file.mat`. E.g., `data.template` will be the variable `template` from the file.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to achieve this using the standard `load` and `save` function. Have a look at this code:

```
image_dir = pwd;
save_dir = pwd;

imds = imageDatastore(image_dir,'FileExtensions',{'.jpg','.tif'});
pxds = pixelLabelDatastore(save_dir,{'nothing','something'},[0 255]);
save('images.mat','imds', 'pxds')

clear
load('images.mat')  % gives you the variable "imds" and "pxds" directly -> might override previous variables
tmp = load('images.mat'); % saves all variables in a struct, access it via tmp.imds and tmp.pxds
```

If you only want to select the variables you want to load use:

```
load('images.mat','imds')        % loads "imds" variable
load('images.mat','pxds')        % loads "pxds" variable
load('images.mat','imds','pxds') % loads both variables
```

**EDIT**

Now I get the problem, but I fear this is not how it is going to work. The Idea behind the `Datastore` objects is, that it is used if the data is too big to fit in memory as a whole, but every little piece is small enough to fit in memory. You can use the `Datastore` object than to easily process and read multiple files on a disk. 
This means for you: Simply save your images not as one big `*mat` file but as multiple small `*.mat` files that only contain one image.

**EDIT 2**

Is it strictly necessary to use an `imageDatastore` for this task? If not you can use something like the following:

```
image_dir = pwd;
matFiles = dir([image_dir '*.mat']);
for i=1:length(matFiles)
    data = load(matFiles(i).name);
    img = convertMatToImage(data); % write custom function which converts the mat input to your image
    % or something like this:
    % for j=1:4
        % img(:,:,j) = cat(3,template{j},template2{j});
    % end

    % process image
end
```

another alternative would be to create a "image" in your 'matreader' which does not only have 2 bands but to simply put all bands (all templates) on top of each other providing a "datacube" and then in an second step after iterating over all small mat files and reading them splitting the single images out of the one bigger datacube.

would look something like this:

```
function data=matreader(filename)
load(filename);
for in=1:4
    data=cat(3,template{in},template2{in}); 
end
end
```

and in your main file, you have to simply split the `data` into 4 pieces.

I have never tested it but maybe it is possible to return a cell instead of a matrix?

```
function data=matreader(filename)
load(filename);
data = cell(1,4)
for in=1:4
    data{in}=cat(3,template{in},template2{in}); 
end
end
```

Not sure if this would work.

However, the right way to go forward from here really depends on how you plan to use the images from `imds` and if it is really necessary to use a `imageDatastore`.

Comment: I may have been unclear, the raw files don't exist as jpg/tif files, they actually are a 2D matrix in a mat file and only exist there as 'raw' data (if I understand the code correctly, this assumes we exported the data as jpg/tifs). More specifically, generating an imds/pxds from a mat file is the problem, not actually saving the structures once they are built

Comment: @edit: I understood that part, the thing is, I have *multiple small mat files that contain 4 images each*, as in 4 template images with a second channel and one output image. Sorry, this is unclear from the question I adapted it.

Comment: @edit2: thanks for this elaborate answer. The reason was mainly to follow the example and then use [trainnetwork()](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/trainnetwork.html#bu6sn4c_sep_shared-train-X) to do the actual training and this seems the way to go for multiple small files

Comment: @more elaboration: I couldn't actually compose a 4D array to train a 2D labelled matrix using syntax trainnetwork(X,Y,layers,opts), otherwise this in conjunction with network snapshots (that could be further trained with manually read-in data) could be an option